# Throw an error when PHP session is not writable?

Tags: php, session

Is there a way to detect and throw an error if PHP session is not writable?

In a large code base, it can be difficult to know if `session_write_close()` was called prior to a session changing code. And when you think you are updating the session, it might be actually not writable, and this can go unnoticed.

Comment: `session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`?

Comment: @frz3993 This looks valid. Thank you. Why don't you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the status of the session.

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    //PHP 7
    throw new Error();
   }
```

After `session_write_close()` has been called the status would be `PHP_SESSION_NONE`

Comment: This is a good answer thank you. I've complemented this a little in my code.  
  
I wrote a wrapper function around session_write_close() so that I can keep the contents of the session array just before it is write closed.  
  
Than at the bottom of my scripts I use your code and compare the current session to the saved contents of the session. If there is a difference I throw the error saying something like "session write was attempted to a non-writable session".